# Function will not echo

Tags: php, function, echo

This is the function.

```
function UsernameFun($ULN) {
if($ULN){
    if(empty($ULN->Nickname)){
        return $ULN->Username;
    } else {
        return $ULN->Nickname;
        }
    }
}
```

$ULN is this

```
if(isset($_SESSION['Username'])) {
$LoggedIn = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username='".$_SESSION['Username']."'"); 
$ULN = mysql_fetch_object($LoggedIn);
}
```

I am putting this to echo

```
echo"Logged in as ".UsernameFun($ULN->Username);
```

If you need to know anything else i will be glad to tell, but as of now i have no idea what else you would need to know.

What i mean by it will not echo is that when i put

```
echo"Logged in as ".UsernameFun($ULN->Username);
```

only "Logged in as" will echo, Username or Nickname will not echo.

Comment: where is your function declaration?

Comment: have you checked your query is returning anything. Try to do with mysql_num_row

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, and should be replaced with `mysqli_*` functions.

Comment: I am sorry this is the first function i have ever try'ed to make, and how would i use mysqli instead of mysql?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are sending only `$ULN->Username` to your function `UsernameFun($ULN->Username)`, it is the only value available in your function. So it is trying to find `$ULN->Username->Username` and `$ULN->Username->Nickname`. Try changing your code to send just the object `$ULN` -

```
echo "Logged in as ".UsernameFun($ULN);
```

Take a look at variable scope with functions and function arguments. It will help to understand why what you pass as an function argument is the only value available in the function. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: @Kolink please share the correct reasoning or suggested edit.

Comment: I don't think it's to do with the scope, rather with what is being passed. Basically I agree with everything except the first sentence.

Comment: @Kolink Thanks for the clarification. I have reworded my answer. Variable scope may not be the exact issue, but understanding it might help the OP know why passing only part of the object prevents them from accessing the rest of the object inside a function.